# Android USB host, 3.2, HID Report Get/Set

Tags: android, usb, host

I have an HID device, specifically -> Silicon Labs USB-FM Radio Reference Design.
This device is exposed as HID.

Using the 3.2 USB Host API, how do I perform a HID_REPORT_GET/SET or its equivalent?

Cheers,
Earlence

Answer (score 3):

I just got a Si470x USB dongle to work on Android. I solved the HID part by writing a small wrapper class around the Android calls:

```
private class HidDevice {
    /** GET_REPORT request code */
    public static final int REQUEST_GET_REPORT = 0x01;
    /** SET_REPORT request code */
    public static final int REQUEST_SET_REPORT = 0x09;
    /** INPUT report type */
    public static final int REPORT_TYPE_INPUT = 0x0100;
    /** OUTPUT report type */
    public static final int REPORT_TYPE_OUTPUT = 0x0200;
    /** FEATURE report type */
    public static final int REPORT_TYPE_FEATURE = 0x0300;

    private Context context;
    private UsbManager manager;
    private UsbDevice device;
    private UsbInterface ifHid = null;
    private UsbEndpoint epIn = null;
    private UsbDeviceConnection connection;

    public HidDevice(Context context, UsbDevice device) throws IOException {
        this.context = context;
        this.device = device;

        for (int i = 0; (this.ifHid == null) && (i < device.getInterfaceCount()); i++)
            if (device.getInterface(i).getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID) {
                this.ifHid = device.getInterface(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < ifHid.getEndpointCount(); j++) {
                    UsbEndpoint ep = ifHid.getEndpoint(j);
                    if ((ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) && (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT))
                        epIn = ep;
                }
            }
        if (this.ifHid == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Device has no HID interface");
        else if (this.epIn == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Device has no INTERRUPT IN endpoint (type USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT, direction USB_DIR_IN");

        this.manager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        this.connection = manager.openDevice(device);
        if (!connection.claimInterface(ifHid, true))
            throw new IOException("Failed to claim HID interface");
    }

    public int getFeatureReport(int reportId, byte[] data, int length) {
        if ((reportId & 0xFF) != reportId)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("reportId may only set the lowest 8 bits");
        return connection.controlTransfer(
                UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN | UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_CLASS | UsbConstants.USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
                REQUEST_GET_REPORT,
                reportId | REPORT_TYPE_OUTPUT,
                ifHid.getId(), data, length, 0);
    }

    public int read(byte[] data, int length) {
        return connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, data, length, 0);
    }

    public int sendFeatureReport(int reportId, byte[] data, int length) {
        if ((reportId & 0xFF) != reportId)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("reportId may only set the lowest 8 bits");
        return connection.controlTransfer(
                UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT | UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_CLASS | UsbConstants.USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
                REQUEST_SET_REPORT,
                reportId | REPORT_TYPE_INPUT,
                ifHid.getId(), data, length, 0);
    }
}
```

Do note that, unlike HIDAPI, Android has a separate argument for the report number when sending or querying feature reports. You do not need to pre-populate the data array with it. However, when a result is returned, the resulting array will have the report number as its first element.

For the high-level stuff, take a look at the [Linux driver](https://github.com/atomic-penguin/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/radio/si470x/radio-si470x-usb.c). `hid_open()` corresponds to the constructor of `HidDevice`, the rest should be straightforward.

Be aware that the lack of unsigned integer types in Java may have unwanted side effects when piecing together data from a `byte[]` array. The workaround is to use `(data[i] & 0xFF)` rather than `data[i]`.

Audio is not transferred over this channel—the dongle implements a separate audio device for that, which seems to be a standard Linux audio device. No experience on that, though (for my project I only need RDS data).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to issue a [control request](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#controlTransfer%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) formatted to issue the GET_REPORT or SET_REPORT along with the report type and report ID. Take a look [section 7.2 in the HID specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf).